# Running jar file from cmd with reference to external jars

Tags: java, jar

I would like to know can I run a jar file from the command, with the jar file using log4j and ojdbc.jar as well.

The 'main' is located in: nmap_logic.jar.
Within the package containing the 'main' is called: "nn.gmap.logic".

I also use 2 external jar files: log4j.jar & ojdbc.jar.

I have tried running:

```
java -cp "nmap_logic.jar;log4j.jar;ojdbc.jar" nn.gmap.logic.NNmain
```

And I get an error that the log4j cannot be initialized.

From the Eclipse environment the application runs fine.

Please let me know how should I execute the command properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't log4j.jar have dependencies?

Comment: Try to give the **full path** to the jars. I believe that there is a difference between what you think is your root folder and what Java thinks about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give the **full path** to the jars. I believe that there is a difference between what you think is your root folder and what Java thinks about it.

Something like `java -cp "c:\myjars\nmap_logic.jar;c:\myjars\log4j.jar;c:\myjars\ojdbc.jar" nn.gmap.logic.NNmain`

Btw, you can also do the following: `java -cp "c:\myjars\*" nn.gmap.logic.NNmain`

Comment: Thank you very much, I cd 'ed to the directory and ran:
java -cp "*" nn.gmap.logic.NNmain.

Works perfectly